# How to load Linux kernel modules from C code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have an application that has both two external kernel modules and a userspace daemon. I want to load the modules from the daemon code, written in C, at startup, and unload them on clean exit. Can I load them in a cleaner way than doing `system("modprobe module");` and unload them using the corresponding `rmmod`?

Comment: Even if you can avoid `modprobe` you probably should not

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**`init_module` / `remove_module` minimal runnable example**

Tested on a QEMU + Buildroot VM and Ubuntu 16.04 host [with this simple parameter printer module](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/91583552ba2c2d547c8577ac888ab9f851642b25/kernel_module/params.c) .

We use the `init_module` / `finit_module` and `remove_module` [Linux system calls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.7/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl#L184).

The Linux kernel offers two system calls for module insertion:

- `init_module`
- `finit_module`

and:

```
man init_module
```

documents that:

> The finit_module() system call is like init_module(), but reads the module to be loaded from the file descriptor fd.  It is useful when the authenticity of a kernel module can be determined from its location in the filesystem; in cases where that is possible, the overhead of using cryptographically signed modules to determine the authenticity of a module can be avoided.  The param_values  argument is as for init_module().

`finit` is newer and was added only in v3.8. More rationale: https://lwn.net/Articles/519010/

glibc does not seem to provide a C wrapper for them, so we just create our own with `syscall`.

insmod.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define init_module(module_image, len, param_values) syscall(__NR_init_module, module_image, len, param_values)
#define finit_module(fd, param_values, flags) syscall(__NR_finit_module, fd, param_values, flags)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *params;
    int fd, use_finit;
    size_t image_size;
    struct stat st;
    void *image;

    /* CLI handling. */
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("Usage ./prog mymodule.ko [args="" [use_finit=0]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (argc < 3) {
        params = "";
    } else {
        params = argv[2];
    }
    if (argc < 4) {
        use_finit = 0;
    } else {
        use_finit = (argv[3][0] != '0');
    }

    /* Action. */
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (use_finit) {
        puts("finit");
        if (finit_module(fd, params, 0) != 0) {
            perror("finit_module");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        close(fd);
    } else {
        puts("init");
        fstat(fd, &st);
        image_size = st.st_size;
        image = malloc(image_size);
        read(fd, image, image_size);
        close(fd);
        if (init_module(image, image_size, params) != 0) {
            perror("init_module");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        free(image);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/91583552ba2c2d547c8577ac888ab9f851642b25/kernel_module/user/myinsmod.c).

rmmod.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define delete_module(name, flags) syscall(__NR_delete_module, name, flags)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("Usage ./prog mymodule");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (delete_module(argv[1], O_NONBLOCK) != 0) {
        perror("delete_module");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/91583552ba2c2d547c8577ac888ab9f851642b25/kernel_module/user/myrmmod.c).

**Busybox source interpretation**

Busybox provides `insmod`, and since it is designed for minimalism, we can try to deduce how it is done from there.

On version 1.24.2, the entry point is at `modutils/insmod.c` function [`insmod_main`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/modutils/insmod.c?h=1_24_2&id=e50f74da70da645c25d7daa81b2d9796a738f718#n39).

The `IF_FEATURE_2_4_MODULES` is optional support for older Linux kernel 2.4 modules, so we can just ignore it for now.

That just forwards to `modutils.c` function [`bb_init_module`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/modutils/modutils.c?h=1_24_2&id=e50f74da70da645c25d7daa81b2d9796a738f718#n148).

`bb_init_module` attempts two things:

- `mmap` the file to memory through `try_to_mmap_module`.

  This always sets `image_size` to the size of the `.ko` file as a side effect.
- if that fails, `malloc`  the file to memory with `xmalloc_open_zipped_read_close`.

  This function optionally unzips the file first if it is a zip, and just mallocs it otherwise.

  I don't understand why this zipping business is done, since we can't even rely on it because the `try_to_mmap_module` does not seem to unzip things.

Finally comes the call:

```
init_module(image, image_size, options);
```

where `image` is the executable that was put into memory, and options are just `""` if we call `insmod file.elf` without further arguments.

`init_module` is provided above by:

```
#ifdef __UCLIBC__
extern int init_module(void *module, unsigned long len, const char *options);
extern int delete_module(const char *module, unsigned int flags);
#else
# include <sys/syscall.h>
# define init_module(mod, len, opts) syscall(__NR_init_module, mod, len, opts)
# define delete_module(mod, flags) syscall(__NR_delete_module, mod, flags)
#endif
```

`ulibc` is an embedded libc implementation, and it seems to provide `init_module`.

If it is not present, I think glibc is assumed, but as `man init_module` says:

> The init_module() system call is not supported by glibc.  No declaration is provided in glibc headers, but, through a quirk of history, glibc does export an ABI for
> this system call.  Therefore, in order to employ this system call, it is sufficient to manually declare the interface in your code; alternatively,  you  can  invoke
> the system call using syscall(2).

BusyBox wisely follows that advice and uses `syscall`, which glibc provides, and which offers a C API for system calls.

Comment: thanks for that! I am writing a C++ program to work with virtual i2c protocol and I used your code to load the kernel module on my machine

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez boa Felipe! Se tiver algum problema com o repo, abre um issue la que agente da um jeito.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%e6%96%b0%e7%96%86%e6%94%b9%e9%80%a0%e4%b8%ad%e5%bf%83-%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6-%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f . Se voce tiver um tempo livre poderia me ajudar nessa questao em como escrever e ler no i2c usando C++? Obrigado https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966483/writing-and-reading-from-a-virtual-i2c-using-c-and-i2c-tools

Comment: Santilli - Eu solucionei usando o codigo de wiringPiI2C com algumas modificacoes para o meu i2c virtual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966483/writing-and-reading-from-a-virtual-i2c-using-c-and-i2c-tools/52971432#52971432 . Obrigado pela dica! Agora eu nao estou conseguindo remover o modulo. Quero dizer: se eu faco a sequincia AddModule > DeleteModule. Funciona. Se eu faco a sequencia AddModule > writeI2C > ReadI2C > DeleteModule. o DeleteModule nao funciona. meu erro: `delete_module: Resource temporarily unavailable`. Ja' tentei colocar um sleep de 1 segundo mas nao funciona.

Answer (score 9):

insmod/rmmod use the functions `init_module` and `delete_module` to do this, which also have a man-page  available. They both declare the functions as `extern` instead of including a header, but the man-page says they should be in `<linux/module.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend against the use of `system()` in any daemon code that runs with root permissions as it's relatively easy to exploit from a security standpoint. `modprobe` and `rmmod` are, indeed, the right tools for the job. However, it'd be a bit cleaner and much more secure to use an explicit `fork()` + `exec()` to invoke them.

Comment: Do you think.. by using fork and exec the process becomes cleaner to remove module.?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a *cleaner* way than `system`.

But for sure, if you want to load/unload the modules from your userspace daemon, then you force yourself to run the daemon as root*, which may not be considered as secure.

*: or you can add the explicit commands in the sudoers file, but this will be a nightmare to manage when deploying your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the same tasks that `modprobe` and Co. do, but I doubt that could be characterized as *cleaner*.