# How to remove a Linux kernel module with an API call instead of a shell command?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

How can i remove .ko module using an API call instead of a shell command. System() function i already know. Is there any other way?

Comment: this link would provide with you the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-can-linux-kernel-modules-be-loaded-from-c-code

Comment: ^^^ I agree with the comments in that link that System() is the more elegant way to achieve this.  However, if you want to know what system calls rmmod is invoking, use 'strace rmmod foomod.ko'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Linux kernel modules be loaded from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-can-linux-kernel-modules-be-loaded-from-c-code) rm and insmod will be analogous.