# How to load a driver in Linux from C++?

Tags: c++, linux, service, linux-kernel, driver

Given  driver name and path, how can I load and start the driver from a `C++` program in Ubuntu.

Does there exists functions similar to `CreateService`,`OpenSCManager`,`OpenService`,etc..

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-can-linux-kernel-modules-be-loaded-from-c-code) could help.

Comment: @LPs : It seems that my system doesnt contain `linux/modules.h`. What to do?

Comment: If you have installed kernel headers you must find it in a subdirectory of /usr/src

Comment: @LPs: Is there some way other than using the system command?? I mean as there is functions like `dlopen` to open libraries dynamically..

Comment: Yes.. the header file exists..

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking for.. With that header you can use kernel to load the driver you want. What is your question then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69807/discussion-between-anzz-and-lps).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Linux kernel modules be loaded from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-can-linux-kernel-modules-be-loaded-from-c-code) Answers will be the same, since kernel APIs are language agnostic, and C heavily dominates low level Linux programming.