# How to trigger a kernel module from shell?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am using Ubuntu with VirtualBox.
I am defining a new command to my shell to output some characteristics(like sibling tree etc.) of child processes. In order to output these characteristics, I created a kernel module and used task_struct. I also tested my kernel module outside of my shell and it works.
Now my problem is how to trigger this kernel module inside my shell(in C code) so that my kernel module will be loaded?

I searched and find that I need to use system calls like modprobe or insmod but did not understand how to use them. I tried the code below, but it did not work:

> setuid(0);
>
> system("/sbin/insmod /.../mymodule.ko");

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what problem did you encounter? what you don't understand? `modprobe` and `insmod` are shell builtins, not syscalls.

Comment: I tried to use system("/sbin/insmod /.../mymodule.ko"); but it did not work. I mean it did not successfully load my kernel module.

Comment: did you use root? try to load it in shell see what happens first.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by using root? If you are asking whether or not I tried "sudo" command, I did. system("/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/insmod ./.../mymodule.ko"); but it also did not work.

Comment: no. this may ask you for a password. you need to run your problem with sudo. `sudo ./your_program`. and get rid of the inside one.

Comment: I did not understand. I am running my c program using gcc command. Should I change that one? What did you mean by "you need to run your problem with sudo" ? Could you please be more specific? I am a beginner, sorry.

Comment: ah. sorry. you need to run you **program** with sudo. how did you run you program?

Comment: From terminal by these commands: "gcc myshell.c" and then "./a.out"

Comment: I tried but still my C code could not load the kernel module.

Comment: try to get in root first: `su`. then `insmod your_module.ko`, see if there are error prompts. then investigate `dmesg | tail` see what the kernel says about your module.

Comment: You should load your module only once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load Linux kernel modules from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-to-load-linux-kernel-modules-from-c-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Loading module using `system()`

You are trying to become **root** in your application (by executing `setuid(0)`), but you don't have permissions to do that (if you run your program as regular user). Instead, you should check if your program was run from root (using `getuid()`). Also, it's good idea to test if your module file exists at all. Here is an example of such code (it's tested and does all checking needed):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define ROOT_UID    0
#define INSMOD_PATH "/sbin/insmod"
#define MOD_PATH    "/.../mymodule.ko"

int main(void)
{
    uid_t uid;
    int res;

    /* Check if program being run by root */
    uid = getuid();
    if (uid != ROOT_UID) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Please run this program as root\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Check if module file exists */
    if (access(MOD_PATH, F_OK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File \"%s\" doesn't exist\n", MOD_PATH);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Load module */
    res = system(INSMOD_PATH " " MOD_PATH);
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading module: %d\n", res);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Module \"%s\" was successfully loaded\n", MOD_PATH);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Save this code as `main.c` file. Be sure to replace MOD_PATH definition with actual path of your module file.

Compile it using next command:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O2 main.c -o load_module
```

Now do the next:

```
$ su
# ./load_module
```

1. First command switches your user to **root** (you will be asked to enter root password). If you don't know **root** password, try using `sudo -s` command instead of `su`.
2. Second command runs your program.

Pay your attention to the last character at the command prompt:

- `#` means you have **root** permissions at this point
- `$` means you only have regular user permissions.

---

### Loading module using `finit_module()`

Using `system()` function in C is usually considered a bad practice (because it takes a lot of time for execution and basically just trying to replace a much more simple Bash script).

If you want to load kernel module in C without using `system()`, you can look into source code of `insmod` tool. See `libkmod/libkmod-module.c` file, `kmod_module_insert_module()` function. You can see those sources [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git/tree/libkmod/libkmod-module.c#n816).

Pay attention to `finit_module()` function call. A good explanation about this [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) can be found at manual pages:

```
$ man finit_module
```

Here is an example how you can use `finit_module()` system call:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ROOT_UID    0
#define MOD_PATH    "/.../mymodule.ko"

static inline int finit_module(int fd, const char *uargs, int flags)
{
    return syscall(__NR_finit_module, fd, uargs, flags);
}

int main(void)
{
    uid_t uid;
    long res;
    int fd;

    /* Check if program being run by root */
    uid = getuid();
    if (uid != ROOT_UID) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Please run this program as root\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Check if module file exists */
    if (access(MOD_PATH, F_OK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File \"%s\" doesn't exist\n", MOD_PATH);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Load module */
    fd = open(MOD_PATH, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Unable to open module file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    res = finit_module(fd, "", 0);
    if (res != 0) {
        perror("Error when loading module");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    close(fd);

    printf("Module \"%s\" was successfully loaded\n", MOD_PATH);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```