# Writing and reading from a virtual i2c using C++ and i2c-tools

Tags: c++, i2c

I am trying to write and read from the I2C bus using C++. My I2C bus is virtual and the first thing is to load the kernel module i2c_stub. I can do everything through bash and now I am porting it to C++. I can open the i2c bus, acquire the i2c bus with a specific address, but I cannot write and read.

I am virtualizing `/dev/i2c-3`. These are the commands if I do in bash:

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install

sudo modprobe -r i2c_stub
sudo insmod i2c-stub.ko chip_addr=0x20
sudo i2cset -y 3 0x20 0x00 0x01
sudo i2cget -y 3 0x20 0x00
```

And this is the C++ code. The writing is failing, also the reading if I change it to be first. I am not sure if it is when I use `ioctl` and the address `I2C_SLAVE, 0x20`. I don't know where to use the address `0x00`.

```
TEST_F(I2CTest, TestReadAndWriteI2C) {
// ------- LOAD i2c_stub KERNEL MODULE -------
char *params;
int fd;
size_t image_size;
struct stat st;
void *image;

// command: sudo insmod /root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko chip_addr=0x20
params = "chip_addr=0x20";
fd = open("/root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko", O_RDONLY);
fstat(fd, &st);
image_size = st.st_size;
image = malloc(image_size);
read(fd, image, image_size);
close(fd);
if (init_module(image, image_size, params) != 0) {
    perror("init_module");
    std::cout
            << "Please make sure that the following commands were executed " <<
            "on the directory [/root/i2c-tests/] before to run the unit test TestAddKernelModule " <<
            "and the file [/root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko] exists." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sudo rmmod i2c_stub" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install" << std::endl;
    GTEST_FAIL();
}
free(image);
GTEST_SUCCESS_("Kernel module loaded.");


//----- OPEN THE I2C BUS -----
int file_i2c = open("/dev/i2c-3", O_RDWR);
ASSERT_GT(file_i2c, 0);
if (file_i2c < 0) {
    GTEST_FAIL(); // Failed to open the i2c bus
} else {
    // std::cout << "Opened i2c port: /dev/i2c-3" << std::endl;
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("Opened i2c port: /dev/i2c-3");
}

// <<<<< The I2C address of the slave
if (ioctl(file_i2c, I2C_SLAVE, 0x20) < 0) {
    std::cout << "ioctl error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    GTEST_FAIL(); // Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave
} else {
    std::cout << "Acquired bus access to i2c address: " << I2C_ADDR << std::endl;
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("Acquired bus access to i2c address: " + I2C_ADDR);
}

//----- WRITE BYTES -----
char bufferToWrite[1];
bufferToWrite[0] = 0x01;
// <<< Number of bytes to write
if (write(file_i2c, bufferToWrite, 1) != 1) {
    GTEST_FAIL(); // Failed to write to the i2c bus
} else {
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("success writing on i2c");
}

//----- READ BYTES -----
char bufferToRead[1];
int numberOfBytesRead = read(file_i2c, bufferToRead, 1);
std::cout << "Data read: " << bufferToRead[0] << std::endl;
printf("0x%02X\n", bufferToRead[0]);
GTEST_SUCCESS_("Data read: " + bufferToRead[0]);
}
```

Comment: I've never touched this stuff, but have you tried to strace i2cset and read it's source code? I'm guessing it won't be hard to figure what's going wrong then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved looking how wiringPiI2C (https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/wiringPi/wiringPiI2C.c) does and modified few points on my code.

```
TEST_F(I2CTest, TestReadAndWriteI2C) {
    // ------- LOAD i2c_stub KERNEL MODULE -------
    char *params;
    int fd;
    size_t image_size;
    struct stat st;
    void *image;

    // command: sudo insmod /root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko chip_addr=0x20
    params = "chip_addr=0x20";
    fd = open("/root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko", O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd, &st);
    image_size = st.st_size;
    image = malloc(image_size);
    read(fd, image, image_size);
    close(fd);
    if (init_module(image, image_size, params) != 0) {
        perror("init_module");
        std::cout
                << "Please make sure that the following commands were executed " <<
                "on the directory [/root/i2c-tests/] before to run the unit test TestAddKernelModule " <<
                "and the file [/root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko] exists." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sudo rmmod i2c_stub" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install" << std::endl;
        GTEST_FAIL();
    }
    free(image);
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("Kernel module loaded.");

    // This initialises the I2C system with your given device identifier.
    int i2cFileDescriptor;
    if ((i2cFileDescriptor = open("/dev/i2c-3", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        GTEST_FAIL();
    }
    if (ioctl(i2cFileDescriptor, I2C_SLAVE, 0x20) < 0) {
        GTEST_FAIL();
    }

    // Write bytes on I2C bus
    union i2c_smbus_data data;
    data.byte = 5;
    i2c_smbus_access(i2cFileDescriptor, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, 0x00, I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &data);

    // Read bytes from I2C bus
    union i2c_smbus_data dataRead;
    if (i2c_smbus_access(i2cFileDescriptor, I2C_SMBUS_READ, 0x00, I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &dataRead)) {
        GTEST_FAIL();
    } else {
        ASSERT_EQ(data.byte, dataRead.byte);
        std::cout << "Read: " << std::hex << static_cast<int>(dataRead.byte ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Read: " << (int) dataRead.byte << std::endl;
        GTEST_SUCCESS_("Read bytes from I2C bus.");
    }

    // Write word on I2C bus
    data.word = 556;
    i2c_smbus_access(i2cFileDescriptor, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, 0x00, I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA, &data);

    // Read word from I2C bus
    union i2c_smbus_data wordRead;
    if (i2c_smbus_access(fd, I2C_SMBUS_READ, 0x00, I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA, &wordRead)) {
        GTEST_FAIL();
    } else {
        ASSERT_EQ(data.word, wordRead.word);
        std::cout << "Read: " << std::hex << static_cast<int>(wordRead.word ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Read: " << (int) wordRead.word << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Read: " << wordRead.word << std::endl;
        GTEST_SUCCESS_("Read word from I2C bus.");
    }
    // return data.word & 0xFFFF ;
}
```

Comment: in reply to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947286/how-to-load-linux-kernel-modules-from-c-code/38606527?noredirect=1#comment92849418_38606527 Let's keep the technical talk in English and on this thread. :-) Sorry but I don't really know this stuff well, but most likely you forgot to free some resource that was allocated? I'd look at the cleanup code of i2cset.

Comment: I guess the problem is related to `init_module` and the way I am loading the kernel module. If I execute this piece of code and comment the rest (everything after `// This initialises the I2C system with your given device identifier.`) I get this error: `*** Error in `./test/sensorTests': free(): invalid pointer: 0x01b64f50 *** Aborted`.

Comment: I am really sorry. I isolated the `init_module` code again in different test and actually my error is this: `*** Error in ./test/sensorTests: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x010b38c8 *** Aborted`